# JLabel Not Appearing

Tags: java, swing, jframe, paint, jlabel

For some reason when I set my JLabel equal to a string it wont appear. I have imported the correct library and added it so it will make the text white and I set it to a font but I am so confused and I am new at java someone help!

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Image;
import java.awt.Point;
import java.awt.Rectangle;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseListener;
import java.util.Random;

public class math extends JFrame{

    //Variables
    public Font text = new Font("Comic Sans MS", Font.BOLD, 50);
    public Color bordercolor = new Color(255,178,102);
    public int anser;
    public int random1;
    public int random2;
    public Random randomnumber1 = new Random(); 
    public Random randomnumber2 = new Random(); 
    public String problem;
    public JTextField textbox = new JTextField(2);
    public JLabel textanser = new JLabel(problem);

    public math(){
        setBackground(Color.BLACK);
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setTitle("Test");   
        setSize(1300,650);
        setResizable(false);
        setVisible(true);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        //  addMouseListener(new ml());     
        }    
        //Paint method
        public void paint(Graphics g){
        g.setColor(bordercolor);
        g.fillRect(0, 0, 50, 700);
        g.fillRect(1250,0, 50,700);
        g.fillRect(0,20,1250,50);
        g.fillRect(0,600,1500,50);
        //Addition Math Problem
        random1 = 1+randomnumber1.nextInt(10);
        random2 = 1+randomnumber2.nextInt(10);
        problem =  random1 + " + " + random2;
        anser = random1 + random2;
        textanser.setLocation(585,275);
        textanser.setFont(text);
        textanser.setText(problem);
        textanser.setForeground(Color.white);
            //Problem on screen
            g.setFont(text);
            g.setColor(Color.WHITE);
            add(textanser);
            //g.drawString(problem,585,275);
            System.out.println(anser);              
            //Text Box
            textbox.setLocation(600, 300);
            textbox.setSize(100,30);
            add(textbox);
            //Action Listener
             textbox.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
             {
                    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
                    {
                          String input = textbox.getText();
                          double intanser = Double.parseDouble(input);                              
                        //Comparing user anser and real anser
                          if(anser != intanser ){

                              JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Incorrect the correct anser was " + anser);  
                          }                              
                          //If anser is correct
                          if(anser == intanser){
                              JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Correct!");                                 
                          }
                    }
             });
            //Integer               
        }   

        public static void main(String[] args) {
        math math = new math();
        }

        public void mouseClicked() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub              
        }           
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You are making erroneous assumptions here. If you place a String into the JLabel and thereby set its contents, if you later change the String variable, this will have no effect on the String displayed by the JLabel. Understand that Strings are *immutable*, meaning that a String *object* cannot change ever. A String variable can refer to a new different String object, but the original String object, remains unchanged.

To change what a JLabel displays you must explicitly call `setText(newString)` on the JLabel.

Also, you should not override a JFrame's paint method, and even if you could do this, you should never change Swing components, or add components within a paint or paintComponent method. The method that should be overridden is a JPanel's paintComponent method, and it should be for painting and painting only, nothing more.

Lots of errors and problems here. I suggest starting over.

---

**Edit**
So again to summarize:

- Don't override a JFrame's paint method.
- If you must do drawing in a Swing GUI, do it in a JPanel or JComponent's paintComponent method.
- Be sure to call the super paintComponent method first thing in your paintComponent override.
- Use this method for painting and painting only. Don't add or remove components from the GUI, don't do any program logic in this method. You cannot control when or if it gets called and so cannot rely on it. Also, the method must be blazing fast else your program will be perceived as slow.
- Don't set position of components. Use the layout managers, often multiple layouts by using multiple JPanels, some nested in others, each with its own layout.
- To change a JLabel's text, call `setText(...)` on the JLabel. Changing the original String variable that was used to create the JLabel will have no effect on the JLabel's display.

  ---

**Edit 2**

- You will need to understand the layout managers, that for instance a JFrame uses BorderLayout by default. So anything added to it without specifying where in relation to the BorderLayout constants gets added BorderLayout.CENTER and covers over all previously added components. Consider using a different layout such as FlowLayout for your simple GUI.

Comment: First of I dont need to override the paint method even I know that and second off a changed the code to setText and nothing appears P.S their is no need to scrap the code

Comment: @user2816767: OK, then keep your code, but show us your code without the paint override, and code that does call `setText(...)` on the JLabel from the ActionListener. Also please see edit to answer regarding GUI layouts.

Comment: how do i not override my paint method? (sorry im kinda of a noob)

Comment: @user2816767: don't have a paint method present; just get rid of it. Instead build your GUI in your class's constructor, not in a paint method.

Comment: I am so confused I just did setText(problem); and added it to the JFrame and nothing is happening

Comment: @user2816767: `"I am so confused..."` -- which is why I mentioned starting over. `"I just did setText(problem); and added it to the JFrame and nothing is happening"` -- you need to show us *exactly* what you're trying now as an edit to your question (usually adding the new code and description of the problem to the bottom of the existing question), if we're to know what is currently wrong.

Comment: Ok where I typed                                                           textanser.setLocation(585,275);
textanser.setFont(text);textanser.setText(problem);
textanser.setForeground(Color.white);                                I added the textanser to the Jframe by doing add(textanser) but nothing appears and I get an error in the console any ideas?